# displaying content from a wordpress site in iphone app

Tags: iphone, wordpress

I am trying to display content from a wordpress site in an iphone app.I downloaded the open source code for the wordpress app and im having difficulty finding the code i need in it.All im trying to do is display the text of a few different pages(no editing or deleting) in my iphone app.Does anyone know if there are any tutorials that could help me or if you know which files the code im looking for is in, in the open source app?
Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

If you just want to display the content of the wordpress site the easiest solution would be to simply display the site in a `UIWebView`.

Downloading the source code of the app will likely not do anything for you. The content of a wordpress site is stored in a database and not in the source code. If the site has an API for accessing the content I would use that. Otherwise you could always parse the generated HTML and extract the content. That's a fragile method that will break if they change the layout of the site.

If I misunderstood your question I apologize, but your question isn't very clear.

Comment: What im trying to do is get the content of a specific site (without the headers and adds), just the text on pages. The website is built using wordpress and when searching around online all i could find was links to download the wordpress app source code.So i did but i couldnt find the what i needed in there.Id say its there but i just dont know where.Sorry about my question not being very clear.Ill give parsing the generated html and extracting the content a shot and hopefully it works out.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then I didn't misunderstand your question. If the site doesn't have an API then your only option is to parse the HTML. There are legal issues that you should be aware of. The content is copyrighted by the author and you can't use it without the authors permission. If you're going to ask the author for permission to use the content you might as well ask him for an API. It should be fairly simple to add an API to wordpress.

Comment: I recommend JSON API. OR failing that, just read the RSS/XML in your iphone app and present it in the app